# Copy value from datepicker and set focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two inputs with datepicker. I want that, when I choose a date on one, it is copied on the other and sets the focus on it. The code below works but after choosing a date in the first datepicker, the focus is on the second input but the datepicker opens and closes immediately.. How can I keep it opened ?

I have tried using `event.preventDefault()` but it did not work. I may not have used it correctly.

```js
function copierDateDebutPourDateFin(elementId, elementValue) {
  $("#" + elementId.substring(0, elementId.length - 3) + "fin").val(elementValue);
  $("#" + elementId.substring(0, elementId.length - 3) + "fin").focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_liv_deb" id="date_liv_deb" placeholder="Date"  onchange="copierDateDebutPourDateFin(this.id, this.value);" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_chg_fin" id="date_chg_fin" placeholder="Date"  />
```

Comment: can you create a working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
$(function(){
   $('#date_chg_deb').datepicker({
       dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
       onClose: function () {
           $("#date_chg_fin").val($('#date_chg_deb').val());
           $("#date_chg_fin").focus();
      }
   });

   $('#date_chg_fin').datepicker({
       dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy'
   });
});
```

The second datepicker remains open after getting the focus !